# .htaccess http://www. and http:// : what is the influence for SEO?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I am trying to improve my SEO rank : I use http://www.woorank.com tool
I have a "sever error" that tells me:

> Be sure that http://roulette-chat.fr
>   and http://www.roulette-chat.fr are
>   not running in parallel.
>
> Redirecting requests from a
>   non-preferred hostname is important
>   because search engines consider URLs
>   with and without "www" as two
>   different websites.
>
> Once your preferred domain is set, use
>   a 301 redirect for all traffic to your
>   non-preferred domain.

Can someone tell me how to solve this issue with the .htaccess ?
regards

Comment: The headline doesn’t match your question. Maybe you should edit the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace example.com with your domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to force the 'www' use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

There are plenty of people in the no-www camp (I used to be one), but remember this can limit the use of sub-domains.

By redirecting one to another (no-www to www or vice versa), you effectively consolidate backlinks to one version of your domain. The major search engines treat www and no-www as seperate pages. You can also make use of the rel=canonical link element as described here: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html